# Alamofire responseJSON Could not cast value of type NSDictionary to custom object

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(todoEndpoint)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON):
                let response: ETOOperatorsList = JSON as! ETOOperatorsList
                delegate.requestWithReference(requestReference: "112", model: response as AnyObject)
            case .failure(let error):
                delegate.requestWithReference(requestReference: "112", error: error)
        }
    }
```

unable to cast giving an **error**

> "Could not cast a value of type '__NSDictionaryI' to 'OperatorsList'."

How can I typecast Alamofire `responseJSON` to a custom object?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to parse it to Dictionary then parse each key-value pair to your object

Comment: You can't arbitrarily cast a type to another... What is ETOOperationList, why are you forcing a cast of your dictionary to this entity?

Comment: @Tj3n I did the same and it works

Answer (score 0):

There is no OJM (Object/Json Mapper) data binding functionality, to convert PONSOs to JSON vice versa, provided by Apple. Either you can do manual mapping or can use some third party one's. e.g.

https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper
https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper